# Can digiKam find images without face tags?

Tags: software, photo-management, face-detection, digikam

I use digiKam (currently version 4.10.0) to manage my photos, and would like to add face tags to images. For images with no tags yet, no problem: I can tag the faces when I tag the images. For images that the face-detection algorithm succeeds on, also no problem: just use the tags from the algorithm. But if the algorithm doesn't find a face and I've already tagged the image (with a regular tag), there's no commonality between the images I want but the absence of a face tag. There's no readily apparent  way to search for images that have regular tags but *don't* have face tags. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to include tag content in the search. E.g., if an image has regular tags for Alice and Bob but a face tag only for Alice, I'd like it to show up so I can tag Bob. But even being able to find an image with a regular tag for Alice and no face tags at all would be helpful.

EDIT: I think that what I essentially need is a way to search specifically for tagged faces in Advanced Search box; it would then be easy enough to reverse the search by picking images that *don't* meet the criterion/a.

Answer (score 2):

Digikam has an SQLite database.  I am not an SQL expert, but such databases allow for powerful search operations.  While I do not have a direct answer, I am hoping the following avenues of research will be helpful.

First start with Digikam's advanced search feature.  Start with Browse->Search and activate the "Advanced Search ..." menu.  Select the criteria "File, Album, Tags" and select a regular tag for Alice. Then add a search group.  Click the "Or" word until "And" appears.  In the buttons below "And," select the "None of these conditions are met." Then, in the second group select a face tag for Alice.  Click either "Try" or "Ok" (I am not sure which.)

If this fails or is too cumbersome, you can resort to searching for SQLite tools.  Firefox has an SQLite Manager add-on which can be used to interrogate the digikam database. Tools exist to convert SQLite databases to an Excel spreadsheet. There are also programming languages (Python, Perl to name two) which can be used to automate the entire search.  But these might be more than you want or can do.

Comment: What I'm trying to find (maybe I'm missing it) is basically a way to search only for face tags. I have checked the Advanced Search box, but all I see there is the first box you mentioned, which searches regular tags. There's nothing apparent in there that distinguishes face tags, since face tags use the tags from the normal hierarchy.

Comment: I have a large collection of photographs. I completely blew away my digiKam 4.6 database and started the "detect faces" process (which is 75% complete after 11 hours).  Because I had a clean database, I had no tags. DigiKam tagged all detected faces as "People/Unknown." From there, did a "Browse People" and clicked "Unknown" and have a slew of photographs which I changed the detected tags to "People/Alice" and "People/Bob."  Because tagging the last "Unknown" face causes the image to "disappear," (it is no longer "Unknown") be sure to add faces which were not detected.

Comment: I've used the people tab to find images that have face tags. It is useful for some purposes, but what I'd like to do is find images _without_ face tags.

Comment: I think I have found your answer.  Browse->Search. Select "Advanced." Leave everything in the first (default) search group unchanged.  This will match all photographs. Add a search group.  Select "And" and "At least one of these conditions is not met." Under "File, Albums,Tags" drop down "Return pictures with tag" and select "People."  Then click "Try."  In my test environment, this returned all photographs without People tags.

Comment: That one didn't work either. It gave me all photos without _regular_ tags in the People category, without regard to face tags (i.e., it returned images both without face tags and with unconfirmed face tags).